# Angular 5 App not working in IE 10

Tags: angular, internet-explorer

I created a new application and ran the command `ng serve`. In Chrome, I could able to see default angular screen with angular logo. But when I access the same URL in IE 10, in the console I see the syntax error.

CLI-info

```
Angular CLI: 1.5.0
Node: 8.9.0
OS: win32 x64
Angular: 5.1.1
... animations, common, compiler, compiler-cli, core, forms
... http, language-service, platform-browser
... platform-browser-dynamic, router

@angular/cli: 1.5.0
@angular-devkit/build-optimizer: 0.0.36
@angular-devkit/core: 0.0.22
@angular-devkit/schematics: 0.0.42
@ngtools/json-schema: 1.1.0
@ngtools/webpack: 1.8.0
@schematics/angular: 0.1.11
@schematics/schematics: 0.0.11
typescript: 2.4.2
webpack: error
```

Polyfills.ts

```
import 'core-js/es6/symbol';
 import 'core-js/es6/object';
 import 'core-js/es6/function';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-int';
 import 'core-js/es6/parse-float';
 import 'core-js/es6/number';
 import 'core-js/es6/math';
 import 'core-js/es6/string';
 import 'core-js/es6/date';
 import 'core-js/es6/array';
 import 'core-js/es6/regexp';
 import 'core-js/es6/map';
 import 'core-js/es6/weak-map';
 import 'core-js/es6/set';

import 'core-js/es6/reflect';
import 'core-js/es7/reflect';

import 'zone.js/dist/zone';
```

Error in IE 10 Console

```
SCRIPT1002: Syntax error 
vendor.bundle.js, line 486 character 1
```

Package.json

```
{
  "name": "ie-angular",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "license": "MIT",
  "scripts": {
    "ng": "ng",
    "start": "ng serve",
    "build": "ng build",
    "test": "ng test",
    "lint": "ng lint",
    "e2e": "ng e2e"
  },
  "private": true,
  "dependencies": {
    "@angular/animations": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/common": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/compiler": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/core": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/forms": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/http": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/platform-browser-dynamic": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/router": "^5.0.0",
    "core-js": "^2.4.1",
    "intl": "^1.2.5",
    "rxjs": "^5.5.2",
    "zone.js": "^0.8.14"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "1.5.0",
    "@angular/compiler-cli": "^5.0.0",
    "@angular/language-service": "^5.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "~2.5.53",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~6.0.60",
    "codelyzer": "~3.2.0",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.6.2",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.1.0",
    "karma": "~1.7.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.1.1",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "protractor": "~5.1.2",
    "ts-node": "~3.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.7.0",
    "typescript": "~2.4.2"
  }
}
```

[image]

Comment: and what is your uglifyjs-webpack-plugin  version?

Comment: what is the target in your tsconfig.app.json?

Comment: show full package.json please

Comment: if the target of your build is es6/es2015, it doesn't support minification - that could be it. What is line 486 of your bundle?

Comment: @pixelbits /***/ "../../node_modules/webpack-dev-server/client/index.js?http://0.0.0.0:0":

Comment: Anyone knoiws how to solve this??

Comment: @venkat7668 Did you find solution??

Comment: I downgraded my application to 4.3.x @sudhir

Answer (score 0):

Please check your polyfill.ts file and check the below link for reference for installing required supporting pollyfills.
https://angular.io/guide/browser-support